# How to count the frequency of variable in pandas column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have the following dataframe: df

```
    date        symbol  open     high      low    close    volume
0   2019-03-01   AMZN  1655.13  1674.26  1651.00  1671.73   4974877
1   2019-03-04   AMZN  1685.00  1709.43  1674.36  1696.17   6167358
2   2019-03-05   AMZN  1702.95  1707.80  1689.01  1692.43   3681522
3   2019-03-06   AMZN  1695.97  1697.75  1668.28  1668.95   3996001
4   2019-03-07   AMZN  1667.37  1669.75  1620.51  1625.95   4957017
5   2019-03-01   AAPL   174.28   175.15   172.89   174.97  25886167
6   2019-03-04   AAPL   175.69   177.75   173.97   175.85  27436203
7   2019-03-05   AAPL   175.94   176.00   174.54   175.53  19737419
8   2019-03-06   AAPL   174.67   175.49   173.94   174.52  20810384
9   2019-03-07   AAPL   173.87   174.44   172.02   172.50  24796374
10  2019-03-01   GOOG  1124.90  1142.97  1124.75  1140.99   1450316
```

I want to get the number of times AAPL occurs in df['symbol']. I don't want to use:

```
df.groupby('symbol').size()
```

Because I am not interested in the others and the original dataset is much larger.

Comment: Try `len(df[df['symbol']=="AAPL"])`

Comment: `df['symbol'].eq('AAPL').sum()`

Comment: what @Quang Hoang proposes is the right thing because it does not perform unnecessary additional operations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

`len(df[df['symbol'] == 'AAPL'])`

It works for me!

Answer (score 1):

You could also try this:

```
df[df['symbol'] == 'AAPL'].shape[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

Pandas *Series* method `value_counts` is exactly what you need.
[Official manual](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.25.0/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html)

```
df['symbol'].value_counts()
```

Comment: OP said: `Because I am not interested in the others`